# how to made logstash work with io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer

Tags: serialization, apache-kafka, logstash, avro, confluent-schema-registry

```
   kafka{
     topic_id => "myTopic"
     bootstrap_servers => "127.0.0.1:9092"
     value_serializer => "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer"
   }
}
```

`[[main]-pipeline-manager] kafka - Unable to create Kafka producer from given configuration {:kafka_error_message=>org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer for configuration value.serializer: Class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer could not be found., :cause=>nil}`

Has anyone made logstash work with io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer ?

Comment: Unclear if that class exists on LogStash Classpath, but also unclear how you plan on adding the schema registry url to the logstash config

Comment: schema registry url is specified by the `avro_schema_registry` codec plugin, as per the docs there - https://github.com/revpoint/logstash-codec-avro_schema_registry

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the ByteArraySerializer and install this codec

https://github.com/revpoint/logstash-codec-avro_schema_registry